# Camel JMS failed to create producer

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I am reasonably new to Camel and have been trying to use requestBody but keep getting an error.  I've simplified my code and still get the same exception.  If my guess is correct the key is probably the message 'Failed to create Producer for endpoint' but I'm not sure how to do that using the Java DSL.

Could someone please point me to the Camel documentation that shows me what I am doing wrong.  Thank you for your help.

Here is the simplified code.

```
package nz.co.home.cameljmsrequest;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.component.activemq.ActiveMQComponent;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // set up the underlying camel context and add the ActiveMQ component
        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.addComponent(
                "jms",
                ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("tcp://192.168.1.150:61616")
                );

        // start the context
        camelContext.start();

        // send the message
        ProducerTemplate producer = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        String requestBody = producer.requestBody("jms:queue:test", 
                "Request Message", String.class);
        System.out.println(requestBody);

        // stop the context
        camelContext.stop();

        // just because we can
        System.out.println("sent message");
    }
}
```

The resulting messages look like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: Request Message]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1287)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:618)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:454)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:136)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:284)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:314)
    at nz.co.home.cameljmsrequest.App.main(App.java:23)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: Endpoint[jms://queue:testCamelActiveMq]. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.initReplyManager(JmsProducer.java:98)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOut(JmsProducer.java:164)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:366)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:337)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:233)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:337)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:192)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:115)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:119)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:290)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:1052)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.getConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:415)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.getConnectionFactory(JmsEndpoint.java:468)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyManager.createListenerContainer(TemporaryQueueReplyManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.doStart(ReplyManagerSupport.java:222)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.createReplyManager(JmsProducer.java:503)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.initReplyManager(JmsProducer.java:94)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite clear from the stacktrace that it is an issue with not specifying ActiveMQ connectionFactory.

The configuration can be done in the Spring XML.

Please, have a look at the jms page for this - [Apache Camel:JMS](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html)

Comment: You are of course completely right. In the Java DSL my solution looks similar to this: 
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://192.168.1.150:61616"); 
    camelContext.addComponent("jms", ActiveMQComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));

Comment: @s.k I use       <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
      <version>2.21.0.fuse-760027-redhat-00001</version>
   <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
   <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
   <version>5.9.0</version>
and there is not ActiveMQConnectionFactory object :(